# create a company to make money by winning Kaggle competition

Tags: data, kaggle

I am thinking of creating a data science company (team) that aims to make money by winning Kaggle competitions. It will be actually a onsite data science learning service but I want to create the company's brand identity like a sport team instead of as a "school." Have you ever heard of such an idea?

Comment: You would make FAR more money consulting.

Comment: Isn't this waaay off topic for the site?

Comment: @rocinante Yes, you are right. This might be on-topic in the Startups SE, but still, it isn't framed well.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. It will be actually off-line data science learning schools taking apprenticeship approach just like others, but I would like to create a brand identity of the company like a sport team as my initial statement. We can honestly try to win the competition but the main revenue source will come from the tuition and I can think of a few other small revenue sources. I just wanted to know if there is such an idea in the industry.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is just inviting open ended conversation.

Comment: I don't think this question is off-topic but I agree that it invites pen ended conversation. I think my question is the best addressed in the data science community rather than startup community in stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

To me, this is a crazy idea because there is absolutely no guarantee your "team" can win anything. You'll need to place yourself like in the top-three, but remember you don't have access to the private leaderboard until the end of the competition. Furthermore, the prize money is minimal. The prize money is designed to offer to an individual, not enough for you to make a living.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I just wanted to spit my idea to see what responses I would get. That's why I just asked "have you heard...". It seems like you haven't and it is a good news. The company will be one of those offline coding schools in big cities, but my idea is to brand it to look distinct for the publicity. I would expect to get a stable stream of consulting works and I think our students will do better on the job placement.

Comment: @Ikuyasu: If you do this, please check you understand Kaggle's rules on private sharing and make sure the submissions comply, because the branding would backfire badly if the end result was disqualification. In short, the school should either enter as a single class/team, or as individuals who must work separately (no shared materials, which would rule out some types of lesson - probably not suitable) or make the shared effort 100% public (which may defeat the purpose of trying to win).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will check out the rule carefully.